# Can I use the Office 2013 installer for Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

If I have a trial of Office 2013 installed on my computer, can I purchase Office 365 Home Premium and just enter the license key in order to activate the product?

Or is Office 365 actually completely different software to Office 2013?

Comment: I would tend to lean toward no but this is really a question that you need to ask Microsoft since they know their licensing the best.

Comment: @garrulinae Its my understand there are very little bits on your own computer when you install Office 365. This is because its entirely a cloud based service. While Office 2013 offers the desktop and the ability the place documents in the cloud.  I would just reinstall Office if I were you.

Comment: It is my understanding that a license from one similar product can not be used on another. The license even specifies the version it is for. Although they are similar Office products, they are different both in product and licensing costs.